# Count how many times while loop was used

Tags: python

so i build a simple while loop to check how many blows needed to cool down the tea. One blow reduces the tea temperature by 10C. The problem is that I have no idea how to go forward with this. I know its something simple but just started python. Thanks

```
tea = 100 #temperature of tea to start with
while tea >= 70:
    print (str(tea) + " C")
    tea = tea - 10
print (" It's ready now ... ")
```

Comment: Why not start a counter at 0 before the loop and increment it by 1 for each "blow"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a variable outside the loop, and increment it in each iteration. So:

```
tea = 100
count = 0
while tea >= 70:
    print(str(tea) + " C")
    tea -= 10   # shorthand for tea = tea-10
    count += 1
print("It's ready now")
print("It took {} blows to cool down".format(count))
```

Comment: oh thanks, i tried to use the count function but I displayed in wrong way. Thank you so much

Comment: and what is the meaning of {} in the last print ? does it mean it will display whatever is in the .format(count) ?

Comment: yes, you're right! In this case count was the argument, it'll format inside {} whatever you pass to the format() method

Comment: ohh I get it . Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
tea = 100 #temperature of tea to start with
count = 0
while tea >= 70:
   print (str(tea) + " C")
   tea = tea - 10
   count += 1
print (" It's ready now ... ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a loop?

```
def steps(current, target, step):
    return int(math.floor((current - target) / float(step)) + 1)

print("It took {} steps!".format(steps(100, 70, 10)))
```

Comment: @user3077730 Great :) Welcome!